# Remove the baseline border of NSWindow title bar

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Is there a way to remove the baseline border of the NSWindow title bar without subclass
the window and implement a title bar view myself? (traffic lights button is real tricky)

I wanted to make view and put it just under the window's title bar without the baseline
border so that the my view below will appear to be "stick" or "continued" from the 
title bar, that is, if I made my view the same color as the title bar.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve that by:

```
window?.toolbar?.showsBaselineSeparator = false
```

Comment: This isn't working in the latest version of MacOS